# Is it possible to make local webserve like xampp/appserve using visual studio installer

Tags: c#, apache

I would like to make my own webserver software like xampp/appseve. Server must running on apache and also php support. I need to do this because I need to add my own php script together this software, Then I can call script after installation on my other computer. I'm not sure that is it possible to combine essential server component using visual studio. Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: may be you just pack them in docker?

Comment: Dear  vasily.sib, Do your have more info or related link.

Comment: you may start learning docker from [here](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/)